# How do I access the indexPath.item in my button function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a program that will search a database and populate the collection view. That currently works. Every item has a "follow" button, and when that button is clicked I need it to perform an action, but I need that action to have access to the `indexPath.item`. The reason why the program is crashing is because the function for the button is hidden in the collection view method, but this is the only way I can gain access to the `indexPath.item`. How do I fix the crashing and still have access to the `indexPath.item`?

```
func followuser(sender: UIButton){
   let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.collectionview)
    if var indexPath :NSIndexPath = self.collectionview.indexPathForItemAtPoint(pointInTable){
        print(pointInTable)
    }
    var relation: PFRelation = (PFUser.currentUser()?.relationForKey("Friendship"))!
    //relation.addObject(users[indexPath.item])

    print(relation)
}


 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("searchcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! searchcustomcell

       cell.follow.addTarget(self, action: "followuser:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: When naming methods in Swift/Objective-C, the naming convention is for the method to begin with a lowercase letter. For instance, in your `func FollowUser` should be `func followUser`.

Comment: Thanks I will update my code.

Comment: Please provide more information as I've outlined in my answer and comments, or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by `indexPath.item`. `NSIndexPath` does not have a property `item`, so that code can't possibly work unless you've created a category of `NSIndexPath`.

And I'm not sure where you are getting the value for your `indexPath` variable.

You have a couple of challenges. The first challenge is to the get the indexPath of the cell that contains the button that was tapped.

One way you do that is to use the `UICollectionView` method `indexPathForItemAtPoint`. You'd take your button's bounds and use one of the UIView methods for converting points between coordinate systems to convert the button's origin from it's coordinate system to the collection view's coordinate system. You'd then take that converted coordinate and use it in a call to `indexPathForItemAtPoint` to get the indexPath that contains the button.

Next challenge: What is it you want to look up by indexPath?

Table views and collection views typically store their model data in either a 1 dimensional array (for a single row of items) or a 2 dimensional array (for a grid of cells.)

You need to take the index path and get either the row or the row and section and use that to index into your model to fetch whatever it is you need to fetch.

However we can't help you with that until you tell us how your collection view is organized and how the model that represents your cell data is stored.

Comment: What do you mean how it organize, how the custom cell looks like?

Comment: I am trying to create a PFRelation between two users. One user searches for another and they show up. There is a follow button in the cell. When that follow button is clicked, the program will know which "cell" the follow button was clicked in.

Comment: I decided to do the `indexPathForItemAtPoint` method, I get the CGPoint of the button, but I am lost on what to do next. I updated my code.

Comment: You need to tell us how your data is organized. Are your cells in rows and columns (a grid) or in a single line (like a cover-flow view or a carousel)? Then how is it stored?